# Magento 2 Command Not working

Tags: magento2, php, error, command-line

Earlier My site was working properly but suddenly it threw the below error.
[image]

Also, When I tried to run the command it threw the below error.
[image]

Can anyone give us a solution on How to fix it? and run all commands properly.

Comment: have you installed any third-party extensions or done any major customization.?

Comment: Are you in the correct folder ? Have you tried running bin/magento without php in the beginning ?

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below commands :

```
rm -rf generated/ var/ 
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:di:compile
php bin/magento s:static-content:deploy -f 
php bin/magento c:f
```

**Command error :** It seems you were running the commands at wrong path. Please run these commands at magento root folder. Currently you were running at php root.

Comment: I am running on Magento root but still it throws the same error.

Comment: Are you getting the same command error via magento root as well Please share the screenshot for same ?
do you have .htaccess file under bin folder ?

Comment: This might get because if the file permission issue as well. Please check the file permissions. Thanks :)